# Remove Cookies In Jquery on logout button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

Hi i am trying to make code for clear cookies in jquery onclick  of logout button but didn't get solution

```
 function logout()
{
 document.cookie = 'Visit=; expires='+new Date(0).toUTCString() +'; path=/FinalVertozz/';
 window.location='../login.html'; 

}
```

cookies details

Name:   Visit
Content:    09850227123455130
Domain: localhost
Path:   /FinalVertozz
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Saturday, October 4, 2014 11:25:45 AM
Expires:    When the browsing session ends

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery/ check this one and try to reuse the function

Comment: This issue is the path. If you remove it things will work (see my answer and example below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the reference of this question and answer from @Russ Cam
[How do I set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery/) 
Use this function to reuse

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;

    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires + "; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = escape(name) + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return unescape(c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length));
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Hope it may help :)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use simple javascript. It's easy.

```
function ClearCookies()
{
   var cookiesCollection = document.cookie.split(";");
   for (var i = 0; i < cookiesCollection .length; i++) 
    {
    var cookieName = cookiesCollection [i];
    var pos= cookieName.indexOf("=");
    var name = pos> -1 ? cookieName.substr(0, pos) : cookieName;
    document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is the path. If you remove it things will work.

```
document.cookie = 'Visit=; expires='+new Date(0).toUTCString();
```

Also, you're not using any jQuery in the above example. The question may be better stated as "remove cookies in JavaScript on logout button".